# Print a hex file in java

Tags: java, printing, command, hex, receipt

I would like to print a hex file on a receipt printer.
For testing, I use the cmd with the command: "copy /b test.hex lpt3:"

Now I would like a java programm, which can send the test.hex to the printer, but not as graphic.

Please, can someone tell me, how I can do that?

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: first - what should this output look like? second - can you print this format to the screen?  Do the latter, then figure out the former.

Comment: First look here: [JavaPOS](http://www.javapos.com/samplecode.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the syntax inside the string anymore, but you can always look that up. In Principle you can do this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start copy /b test.hex lpt3:");
```

[Here is the reference!](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html)

So if you find no way to access that custom printer directly from java you can first create that .hex file, then use exec() to send it.

Comment: I dont work often with Runtime, can you tell me the command for Close, after your commandline? I have try: 1. Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start copy /b test.hex lpt3:"); 2. Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c stop");

Comment: close? i dont understand what you want to close.

Comment: ahh, the dos-box stays open. i previously only tried `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start explorer");` In which case there is no dos-box. Let me try something to get that dos-box closed again...

Comment: `String[] commands = new String[2];
    commands[0] = "cmd /c start copy a.java b.java";
    commands[1] = "cmd /c start exit";
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);`

Comment: Sure! And thanks for accepting the answer although you have to construct it yourself from the answer and the additional comment.